# Is there any option to open a file (without extension) as sql file in PL/SQL developer?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Is there any option to open a file (without extension) as sql file in PL/SQL developer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a SQL script, use File > Open > SQL Script:

[image: PL/SQL Dev File Open SQL Script]

In the File > Open dialog, you need to change the default file type from "SQL script (.sql)" to "All files":

[image: File Open dialog]

If you open a file by drag & drop, the default seems to be to treat it as a Program Window. You can change the window type by right-clicking and choosing *"Change Window To"*.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me explain it again. I am able to open a file without extension in PL/SQL developer but it gets identified as as a package or program file. I need a option to open a file without extension in SQL file editor. It hides all options that are usually available in sql editor window of PL/SQL developer- Like query execution, code formatting, etc.

Comment: I've clarified my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Perfect !! Your solution helped.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you could mark it as the accepted answer, [I could use the points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400506/congratulations-for-reaching-a-million-gordon-linoff?cb=1) ;)